# How to determine completion time on different CPUs

Tags: java, pdf

I am writing a Java app that processes some files (PDFs in my case).
I would like to give an estimate to when the task will finish.

While i can give a good estimation of the time needed on my PC, the same time will not apply to a different PC, because it will have a different CPU.

How can I estimate how long will my program run on a machine with with a slower/faster CPU? Can Java rate a CPU or something like that?

I understand that similar CPUs may perform very differently, depending on what the program needs from that CPU, but i am looking for a rough estimate.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is to start processing files and calculate an ETA during the processing

Comment: @BackSlash - That will still not give him the result he wants. I don't think it is a good idea to (try) measure execution time in terms apart from *Time Complexity* (which is guaranteed). Any other thing that he tries will not give him correct results.. He might get proper results for his machine, but it cannot serve as a rough estimate for other machines with different architecture / OS / load

Comment: @BackSlash - What you are suggesting would be to send signals during processing, and adjust my prediction in real time? That could work, but most of the processing is out of my control (so i cant just add messages during the process).